# How to correctly query my friend table with its many to many relationship with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, exists, sql-in

I am building a simple application using MySQL as the database. I have a user table with varying information, but I also have a friends table. Each user has it's own ID which is referenced in the friend table when a request is initiated.

My friends table is pretty simple:

```
id              int       NO    PRI                 auto_increment
date            datetime  NO    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT_GENERATED
user_one_id     int       NO            
user_two_id     int       NO            
request_status  tinyint   NO
```

My issue is when trying to query my table to find a specific user's friends. My two subqueries in the below query both work fine on their own, however when I include them in the main query, I get no results. No errors, but also no results.

If the logged in user's ID is 1, then -

```
SELECT id, display_name, join_date, profile_image_url 
FROM user WHERE id IN
    (SELECT user_one_id FROM friend WHERE user_two_id = 1 AND request_status = 1) 
AND id IN 
    (SELECT user_two_id FROM friend WHERE user_one_id = 1 AND request_status = 1);
```

The query is supposed to account for the user's ID being in either column, depending on who actually initiated the friend request.

I apologize if this seems like a dumb question, but we all gotta learn sometime.

Please let me know if any additional information would help.

Comment: You use AND between the conditions - i.e. you search the user whose ID is in both user_one_id and user_two_id **in the same row**.

Comment: Oh. That's embarrassing. You have indeed 'learnt' me something today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your code would work if you used OR instead of `AND` for the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, but I propose a simpler solution with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.display_name, u.join_date, u.profile_image_url 
FROM user u
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM friend f 
  WHERE f.request_status = 1
    AND (f.user_one_id, f.user_two_id) IN ((u.id, ?), (?, u.id))
);
```

Replace `?` with the id of the user that you want to search.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this unfortunately did not work. Running it with the information that is already in my database for user 1 returned only a singular result, whereas user 1 should have 4 friends.

Comment: @AndrewAtwood post sample data in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7 so that I can check.

Comment: Weirdly enough, it works on the fiddle. 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=40200e6fd25ce93cada4f36f88e12f09

Comment: @AndrewAtwood then doublecheck the code that you use.

Comment: I dropped my friend table, remade it with the information in the fiddle, as well as the users table. Re-running your query still only provides a singular result. Could it be a difference in version? I am running 8.0.27

Comment: Alright, definitely something wonky going on. I tried my initial query (replacing AND with OR) on the Fiddle and that returned the correct results. Going to continue troubleshooting, but I appreciate all of your help. I'll be sure to mark your answer as THE answer if I get this figured out.

Comment: The fiddle works for Mysql 8.0.27 too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40200e6fd25ce93cada4f36f88e12f09

Comment: Just to update, I was able to figure out. I had been creating the tables through the UI. I realized at the end that it was appending this line to the end of my create statement when done through the UI.

ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

I don't 100% understand what it does, but when I removed that statement and ran my SELECT, we got the desired results. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndrewAtwood AUTO_INCREMENT=28 starts the autoincrement column not from 1 but from 28: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73a10ecdd4868d3a7adbc28932d7cfce